# OnItemClickListener in ListView not identifying click

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I've searched and tried to implement different solutions to this problem but nothing has solved this issue. I have a custom listview class and when its called from my main activity the first time everything works as expected. Clicking on an item yield in moving to the next activity. However when I am in my new activity and call identical code for the OnItemClickListener it doesn't react to clicks. Any help in this would be great as I am stumped.

OCForumsAppActivity is my main activity, and then BothActivity is where my onItemClickListener isn't working.

OCForumsAppActivity.java:

```
package com.ocforums.application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.ocforums.application.R;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;




public class OCForumsAppActivity extends Activity {


    //private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;


    public String md5(String s) {
        try {
            // Create MD5 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(s.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            // Create Hex String
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void loginfunc(String un,String pwd) {
         try {
             String pmd5sum = md5(pwd);
             //HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
             DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://portal.sun.com/portal/dt");
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
             String postURL = "http://www.overclockers.com/forums/login.php?do=login";
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_username", un));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_md5sumpassword", pmd5sum));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookieuser","1"));
                 UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                 post.setEntity(ent);
                 response = client.execute(post);
                 entity = response.getEntity();
                 cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();

                 if (entity != null) {    
                     Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                 }
                 client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


    }

    /* private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public MyCustomAdapter() {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public void addItem(final List<List<String>> output2d) {
                mData.add(output2d);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            public int getCount() {
                return mData.size();
            }


            public String getItem(int position) {
                return (String) mData.get(position);
            }


            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
                ViewHolder holder = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.id.listView1, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.textView.setText((CharSequence) mData.get(position));
                return convertView;
            }

        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView textView;
        }*/


      public static String gethurl()
      {
         return OCForumsAppActivity.hurl;
      }
      public static void  sethurl(String newh)
      {
          OCForumsAppActivity.hurl = newh;
      }
      public static void sethreflist(List<String> newlist)
      {
          hrefslist = newlist;
      }
    CustomListView lv = new CustomListView();
    public static String hurl;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    static List<String> hrefslist;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(OCForumsAppActivity.this, "Working...", "request to server", true, false);
        new ParseForums().execute("http://www.overclockers.com/forums/?styleid=23");


        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

             Log.i("testing",hurl); 

             if(hurl.matches("(?i).*forumdisplay.*")){

                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BothActivity.class);     
                 startActivity(newActivity);


             }
             else if(hurl.matches("(?i).*showthread.php.*")) {
                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ThreadActivity.class);     
                 startActivity(newActivity);
             }
             else if(hrefslist == null){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Confused?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 //TODO add context menu for quote and reply
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Very Confused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case R.id.login:    
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LinearLayout lila1= new LinearLayout(this);
            lila1.setOrientation(1); //1 is for vertical orientation
            final EditText usernametextbox = new EditText(this);
            final EditText passwdtextbox = new EditText(this);
            lila1.addView(usernametextbox);
            lila1.addView(passwdtextbox);
            alert.setView(lila1);
            alert.setTitle("Login");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String uname = usernametextbox.getText().toString().trim();
                    String passwd = usernametextbox.getText().toString().trim();
                    loginfunc(uname,passwd);
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
         break;
         case R.id.settings:
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Perhaps one day...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         break;   

         case R.id.UnansweredThreads:
             hurl ="http://www.overclockers.com/forums/search.php?do=process&replyless=1&replylimit=0&exclude=78,124,37,167,186,186,187,21,144,18,179,150,181,182,183,11,164,95,151,123,27,28,29,30,31,32,142,170,33,36,67,62,63,65,11,19,200&nocache=0";
             Intent newActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ThreadActivity.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity);
         break;   

         case R.id.MyPosts:
             hurl = "http://www.overclockers.com/forums/search.php?do=getdaily&exclude=123&nocache=1";
             Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ThreadActivity.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity1);
         break;   


        }
        return true;
    }



    class ParseForums extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<List<String>>> {

        protected List<List<String>> doInBackground(String... arg) {
            List<List<String>> combined2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>();

            try
            {
                HtmlHelper hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
                List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("forumtitle");

                for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = links.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
                {
                    TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                    output.add(divElement.getText().toString());
                    hrefs.add(divElement.getAttributeByName("href").toString());
                }

                combined2d.add(output);
                combined2d.add(hrefs);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return combined2d;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<String>> output2d) {

            pd.dismiss();
            output2d.size();
            Log.i("size",Integer.toString(output2d.get(0).size()));
            Log.i("size",Integer.toString(output2d.get(1).size()));
            ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            listview.setAdapter(lv.new MyCustomAdapter(OCForumsAppActivity.this, R.layout.row , output2d.get(0)));



        hrefslist = output2d.get(1);
        }
        }




    }
```

BothActivity.java:

```
package com.ocforums.application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;

import com.ocforums.application.CustomListView.MyCustomAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class BothActivity extends Activity{





    List<String> foutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> houtput = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    CustomListView lv = new CustomListView();
    String hurl;
    List<String> hrefslist;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String qhurl = OCForumsAppActivity.gethurl();
        String shurl = "http://www.overclockers.com/forums/"+qhurl+"&styleid=23";

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(BothActivity.this, "Working...", "request to server", true, false);
        new ParseBoth().execute(shurl);
        Log.i("where ami?","back from execution");
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                hurl = hrefslist.get((int) id).replace("amp;","");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Log.i("testing",hurl); 

             if(hurl.matches("(?i).*forumdisplay.*")){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 OCForumsAppActivity.sethurl(hurl);
                 BothActivity ba = new BothActivity();
                 ba.onCreate(null);


             }
             else if(hurl.matches("(?i).*showthread.php.*")) {
                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ThreadActivity.class);     
                 startActivity(newActivity);
             }
             else if(hrefslist == null){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Confused?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 //TODO add context menu for quote and reply
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Very Confused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
            }
        });
    }

    class ParseBoth extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<List<String>>> {

        protected List<List<String>> doInBackground(String... arg) {
            List<List<String>> combined2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> Toutput = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> Threfs = new ArrayList<String>();

            try
            {
                HtmlHelper hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
                HtmlHelper hh2 = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
                List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("forumtitle");
                List<TagNode> Tlinks = hh2.getLinksById("(?i).*thread.*");

                for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = links.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
                {
                    TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                    output.add(divElement.getText().toString());
                    hrefs.add(divElement.getAttributeByName("href").toString());
                }

                for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = Tlinks.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
                {
                    TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                    Toutput.add(divElement.getText().toString());
                    Threfs.add(divElement.getAttributeByName("href").toString());
                }
                Log.i("size",Integer.toString(output.size()));
                Log.i("size",Integer.toString(hrefs.size()));
                Log.i("size",Integer.toString(Toutput.size()));
                Log.i("size",Integer.toString(Threfs.size()));

                combined2d.add(output);
                combined2d.add(hrefs);
                combined2d.add(Toutput);
                combined2d.add(Threfs);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return combined2d;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<String>> output2d) {

            pd.dismiss();
            output2d.size();


            foutput.addAll(output2d.get(0));
            foutput.addAll(output2d.get(2));

            houtput.addAll(output2d.get(1));
            houtput.addAll(output2d.get(3));

            Log.i("size",Integer.toString(foutput.size()));


            setContentView(R.layout.main);

           Log.i("where ami?","going");
           ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
           listview.setAdapter(lv.new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row , foutput));
           Log.i("where ami?","back");


            hrefslist = houtput;
        }
        }

}
```

CustomListView.java:

```
package com.ocforums.application;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListView extends ListActivity {
    List<String> lists;
    Context fcontext;
    public void makelistview(List<String> list, Context context){
        lists=list;

        setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(context, R.layout.row, lists));
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        fcontext = context;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        lists=objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.forumlist);
        label.setText(lists.get(position));
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (lists.get(position).matches("AMD*")){
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.forum_new);
        }
        else{
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.forum_old);
        }

        return row;
        }
        }
}
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:contentDescription="OCForums thread icon"
    android:src="@drawable/forum_new" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/forumlist"
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should shorten your code to the relevant parts. No one will read that amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
```

To this..

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: I had set it to false as I read that solved it for others, but setting it to true results in OnItemClickListener still not functioning. Was worth a shot though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same problem before. You need to change the root node for your row.xml file to RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. I'm not 100% sure why this works, but it did so for me.

Of course, you will also have to add a tag saying:

`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"`

inside your TextView node.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me, but you have provided me with a new avenue to look down, so I'll see if its not some weird xml issue.